# The line does not slide/animate in left direction if 2nd, 3rd, etc. menuitem is active. Right direction is working properly

Tags: html, css, menuitem

I found this question very useful: [CSS slide bottom border on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181449/css-slide-bottom-border-on-click/42474633#42474633)

However, I am having problems to make the bottom line stay (the last child element) on the current active page.

I created 3 test pages named test1.html, test2.html and test3.html.
All of them include the same css from the answer from @Zay Lau and the animation of the bar works very nice.

```
<div class="topmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="test1.html">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="test2.html">Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="test3.html">Test 3</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to make current active page highlighted (underlined by the last-child), meaning if user would be on test2.html the topmenu on this page would have its "Test 2" item highlighted. But my experience with css and html is very short. I know that the jQuery code needs to be wrapped in 'script' tag and put into my head part of html and also I need to link the jQuery from google. Even tho I do this, the page navigation does not highlight the active page.

(I just created account here, I want to learn, please, if my description is not clear enough, just ask for more detail) Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: please add your full code for reference

Comment: I made example page here (http://kvartet.000webhostapp.com/kontakt.html) if you notice, I have set class="active" to menuitem "Kontakt" and the animation works to righ tdirection but it does not work to the left.

Comment: this would be lot easier for us to solve your problem if you add code here instead of giving us links to 3rd party sites, if you can't add a snippet here then atleast make a `fiddle` of it, or use [Codepen](http://codepen.io) and share the link here